# Generate Authorization token for MuleSoft API in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, mulesoft, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to call Mulesoft API endpoint from NetSuite user event script. I need to generate token to send it with API call.
Question:

1. should i create schedule script to generate the token and store it somewhere?
2. how often the token should be refreshed?

Postman token generation is working fine. I would love to know how should I setup this in NetSuite.

Postman:
[image]

Comment: how often the token should be refreshed? when they expire

Comment: @aled I wasn't told by mulesoft that there is an expiration for the token. If there is no expiration then can i use the token i generated from postman?

Comment: @aled this is the response on postman.  Response: {"access_token":"access token","scope":"Mulesoft","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":14400}

Comment: 1) you can see in the response that the token expires in 14400 seconds. Your client needs to be prepared to handle whatever expiration is returned. 2) you are confusing the terminology. Postman is requesting a token, not generating it. Your Mule application is somehow generating the token returned.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies in advance as I cannot comment, low Rep.

I haven't worked with Mulesoft or Oauth2, I mostly work on Oauth1.

According to your comments, it expires in 4 Hours. I suggest you store the generated Access Token in Script Parameter. [NetSuite Script Parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/part_1542289448.html). You can call task.create to schedule a script to refresh the Access Token every 4 hours as stated on the notes on this page [Referencing Script Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/chapter_N2999784.html)

EDIT: Had to confirm few things regarding Script Parameter. According to some articles, Script Parameter are global and can be called from different scripts (has to be set as company preference when creating parameter). So, scheduled script and storing it to a parameter and having your UE Script fetching the value of that parameter will work.

Comment: Just to add, if access token is being accessed by multiple scripts you could make use of N/cache instead of the Script Parameter.

Comment: @PaoloUrielN.Enriquez could give an example? I haven't used N/cache myself and had a quick look, seems to be a useful little module I could use myself. Though I think OP will only have 1 Script accessing the Token.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code sample to [@Nukedd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19585411/nukedd)'s answer.

Here's an example of storing/fetching access token in Cache.

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'MY_CACHE';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN';

const cache = require('N/cache');

// Storing access token to server cache
const storeAccesstoken = () => {
    var myCache = cache.getCache({
        name: CACHE_NAME,
        scope: cache.Scope.PRIVATE
    });
    myCache.put({
        key: ACCESS_TOKEN,
        value: '12345accesstoken',
        ttl: 14400
    });
}

// Fetching access token from server cache
const getAccessToken = () => {
    const myCache = cache.getCache({
        name: CACHE_NAME
    });
    const myAccessToken = zipCache.get({
        key: ACCESS_TOKEN,
        loader: loaderFunction
    });
    return myAccessToken;
}
```

Please see the following:

- [N/cache Module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4642573343.html)
- [cache.Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4655722738.html)

Note: This is only supported by server scripts.